# copy a table to another and add a column that is the tablename of the source

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I want to copy some tables who all have the same prefix into one table.
The destination table should have on column more then the source, that is the name of the source table.

I tried this :

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_dest` (`nr`,`n1`,`n2`,`n3`,`n4`,`n5`,`table`) 
SELECT `a`.`nr`, `a`.`n1`, `a`.`n2`, `a`.`n3`, `a`.`n4`, `a`.`n5`, `b`.`table`  
FROM `tbl_src` `a`, `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`.`TABLE_NAME` `b`
```

but it is not working well.
Practically in the **tbl_dest** the value of the column **table** should be '*tbl_src*' for all data originating from *tbl_src*

Any idea?

Comment: *but it is not working well.* Is not an error description. Do you get an error message or what is the problem?

Comment: You know the tablename already it is tbl_src, so why do you want to get again?

Comment: the source tables are called like this: 'prefix_blablabla' , so I want to make this automatic, when a new table with this prefix appears the tbl_dest should be rewritten by concatenating all tables with the same prefix in one table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a constant:

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_dest` (`nr`,`n1`,`n2`,`n3`,`n4`,`n5`,`table`) 
    SELECT `a`.`nr`, `a`.`n1`, `a`.`n2`, `a`.`n3`, `a`.`n4`, `a`.`n5`,
       'tbl_src' 
    FROM tbl_src a;
```

I would also advise you to dispense with all the backticks.  They just make the query harder to write and to read.